# Чем можно заменить метод Resources.Load()?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть 1000 спрайтов(фотографии фонов для каждого нового уровня). Данные 1000 спрайтов помещены в папку Resources. Каждый фон подписан Lvl + номер уровня. Нужный фон вызывается при загрузке сцены в методе Start() в зависимости от номера уровня.

```
    public Image image;
    private string k;

    private void Start()
    {
        k = "Lvl" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LvlNumber");
        image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(k);
    }
```

Спустя несколько минут нахождения в игре она начинает подлагивать. Я подозреваю, что это связано отчасти с тем, что я использую Resources.Load(). Какими другими способами я могу воспользоваться, чтобы использовать на каждом уровне разный спрайт?

Comment: 1. нужно не гадать, а смотреть в профайлере. 2. 1000 спрайтов можно разместить на одной единственной картинке. А на обьектах использовать оффсет. Это если причина тормозов в этом. Но что-то мне подсказывает что пиричина совсем в ином.

Comment: @Andrew `1000 спрайтов на одной картинке`  вы же понимаете, что это изображение с разрешением 32х32 картинки. Учитывая, что это "фон", то размеры там ну как минимум 480p, если не 720p или вообще не 1080p. Представляете себе размер такой текстуры? Да пускай там даже будет размер 32х32 пикселя, зачем хранить в памяти первый и последний уровни одновременно?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker если я правильно понял текст, то это не только фон, а вообще текстуры для уровней. Вряд ли там 1000 уровней с разным дизайном каждый - лично по моему мнению это было бы по меньшей мере странным. И если я правильно понял, то я утверждаю что для каждого отдельного уровня "пак" текстур должен быть единым файлом и это позитивно скажется на быстродействии. Не очень коректно написал свою мысль.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker кроме того я посоветовал смотреть в профайлер прежде чем что-то делать с текстурами. Т.к. догадка на тему почему тормозит -  ничем не подкреплена. На самом деле там наверняка проблемы с програмным кодом, а совсем не в текстурах.